# How valid are partial solutions?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, participation

I'm new to answering questions on SO and I am getting discouraged.

[Perl create class object by using variable as class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402674/perl-create-class-object-by-using-variable-as-class-name/17402867?noredirect=1#comment25276041_17402867)

I know my stuff on what I answer and I try to offer new directions to investigate rather than fully working solutions.

Am I right to take this approach?

Comment: you are under no obligation to provide "fully working solutions" but you should answer the question. If it's too hard to answer (how do I encrypt things? How do I get started in Perl?" then don't answer. Deliberately holding back and answering "take a look at this, this, and this" is not a good answer.

Comment: I wasn't holding back just trying to keep the solution concise. The original question has been edited into correct syntax so I wanted to give a short simple answer. I think I will stop with this approach though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Reviewing some of your negatively voted answers:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17402674/perl-create-class-object-by-using-variable-as-class-name/17402867#17402867) just wasn't what the OP was looking for.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17401819/102937) seems to suggest that you didn't understand that you can edit your answers to fix them (you posted a comment to your answer with the fix instead).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17387015/102937) is a link-only answer.  See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: I try to link off SO as other site could come and go. But the links could change anyway. I will stop with the linking and I will edit solutions which are wrong rather than add follow up comments.

Comment: As a general rule I always feel a link (external or otherwise) helps an answer, but if the answer could not "live" without the link then its a bad answer